# Правильный вывод русского текста с MySQL

Tags: кодировка

Доброе время суток. Такая возникла проблема, в бд храниться текст русским языком, но при попытки вывести его возникает ошибка с вопросами, тобишь вместо текста знаки вопроса. Исходный код страницы:

`<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php'; //Подключение к базе данных
include 'config.php'; //Подключение к настройкам
mysql_query('set names windows-1251',$db);  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<meta charset='windows-1251'>
<meta content='<?php echo $find; ?>' name='keywords'>
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
<link rel='alternate' type='application/rss+xml' title='<?php echo $title; ?>' href='<?php echo $site; ?>/rss/rss.php'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='1'"));
echo $row['txt'];
?>
</body>
</html>`

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
mysql_query ("set character_set_client='cp1251'"); 
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='cp1251'"); 
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='cp1251_general_ci'");
```

Comment: Спасибки, гуд, работает)